# new Google Sheets: set text wrapping to Clip programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There's a new text wrapping mode called *Clip* in the new Google Sheets.

`getWraps()`/`setWraps()` still works with boolean values. When I set wrap value to `true`, text in that cell is displayed in *Overflow* mode.

I've found no trace of any new function to set the text wrapping to *Clip*.

Does anybody know how to deal with that?

Answer (score 7):

There's new method available for setting text wrapping strategy: [Range.setWrapStrategy(strategy)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setwrapstrategystrategy)

Example:

```
// Sets all cells in range B2:D4 to use the clip wrap strategy.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D4");

range.setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.CLIP);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use copyTo(destination) paste a cell having the clip wrap mode to the destination cell, then change the other range properties.

Also star the Google Apps Script issue [5482](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5482) : Ability to set text wrapping mode to Clip.